# MongoDB pagination with grouped item

Tags: performance, mongodb, pagination

I am building a messaging module into an existing web app. We are storing the messages in mongo with a data structure that something looks like:

```
{
  id: "",
  inResponseToMessageId: ""
  to: []
  cc: []
  bcc: []
  subject: ""
  body: ""
  owners: [{id:4, status:"read", folder:"inbox"}, {id:1, status:'unread', folder:'inbox'}]
  dateSent:
}
```

The client would like us to be able to display messages in both a **conversation view** and a **singleton view**.

I am having trouble figuring out an efficient query that can

1. Return results grouped by message thread.
2. Work well with pagination.
3. Sortable by date and subject.

I can modify the data structure however I need in order to get this to work well.

**Below are a few possible solutions but they all seem to fall short:**

- Store messages as children of a thread object.
- Add a threadId to each message and then query and group by threadId.
- Create some type of meta information object that helps.

The problem with the standard mongo `group` or  `$group` function is that I imagine it will perform very poorly when the collection is large. We are expecting there to be hundreds of millions of messages in the collection.

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked, but: is Mongo really a requirement or do you have flexibility choosing your document store? The problem you describe is really a relational one...

If you can choose another storage solution then I'd suggest OrientDB instead of Mongo since it can act as a document store and your hands won't be tied as they are now. Whichever you decide to go with I suggest you actually run some benchmarks to see if your expectations match actual performance!

Comment: @easuter. Thanks for the response. I am happy to use a relational db, but i don't think it will solve the problem. Can you elaborate on how a relational model will help?

Comment: Firstly, sorry for the delay in replying! Document stores like Mongo are great if you're storing strictly hierarchical data and when you're **sure** that your schema (heh...) will be static forever.
A classic example of this problem was [Diaspora's initial use of MongoDB as the project's storage](http://tinyurl.com/mzux7tq), I highly recomend reading it.

Going back to that last point: you don't know for sure if your client's requirements will change in the future, and by then you may have "coded yourself into a corner", making the switch to something else very painful.

Answer (score -1):

Put a `threadId` on your messages.

> Return results grouped by message thread.

You can find messages by thread like

```
db.messages.find({ "threadId" : id })
```

I don't think there's any need to group them in the sense of the `$group` operator.

> Work well with pagination.

Pagination for the messages in what order? Pagination works well if you have a sort on a unique field. `dateSent` should be unique if you keep it to millisecond precision, so you can paginate on it.

```
// page 1
db.messages.find({ "threadId" : id }).sort({ "dateSent" : -1 }).limit(25)
// page 2
db.messages.find({ "threadId" : id, "dateSent" : { "$gt" : <25th date sent> } }).sort({ "dateSent" : -1 }).limit(25)
```

> Sortable by date and subject.

Who sorts messages by subject? Anyway, this is just a matter of creating the right indexes if you want to retrieve messages in date or subject order. Depending on your requirements you might be doing this sorting for a client view, where it might not be necessary to have the database sort the results. The client could do it for the returned subset instead.

Comment: This wont work. Your query will return messages but they wont be grouped by thread. If the 25 most recent messages all belong to the same thread then it will just return the messages of 1 thread and not 25 threads. The inbox needs to show 25 threads not 1.